# elasticsearch painless script to add object field into document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a rather basic requirement, I would like to add an object to a document with painless within a query for update.

This is the object I would like to add

```
"memoire": {
      "codeActe": "C",
      "docType": "M",
      "uuid": "added ",
      "nonFacturable": false,
      "published": false
    },
```

I tried

```
    POST /csa_encounters/_update_by_query
{
  "script":
{ "source": """

  ctx._source.memoire.codeActe = "C";
  ctx._source.memoire.docType= "M";
  ctx._source.memoire.uuid = "added ";
  ctx._source.memoire.nonFacturable = false;
  ctx._source.memoire.published =false
""",
"lang": "painless"
},
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                { "query_string" : { "query" : "140c7646", "fields" : [ "_id" ] } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the message null pointer exception as the field does not exist of course

```
"type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "ctx._source.memoire.codeActe = \"C\";\n  ",
      "                   ^---- HERE"
    ],
 ...
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": null
    }
  },
  "status": 400
```

I am not able to figure out how to create the object as a new field if it does not exist already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the field `memoire` doesn't exist in your document.
So just add the following lines at the beginning of your script:

```
if (ctx._source.memoire == null) {
    ctx._source.memoire = [:];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error `type=no_viable_alt_exception, reason=null` when doing this.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown please create a new question possibly referencing this one but explaining the context of your issue